# How to force sign out user if firebase.app().auth().signOut() return error?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How to force sign out user if firebase.app().auth().signOut() return error ?

```
firebase.app().auth().signOut()
      .then(() => console.log("good"))
      .catch(() => {
        /*I still need to sign out user*/
      });
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I get no error, I just want to handle this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very unlikely you get an error in that case as this operation simply clears the state from local storage (`localStorage`, `indexedDB`, `sessionStorage`). The only possible error could be related to that (access to these local storages fails for some reason which is rare if you already were able to write to them). It would be better to show the error to the end user so they can take some other action such as clearing their cookies for the site, etc, especially if the user is using some shared device.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to display an error to the user saying that they were not logged out and they should try again.

Or, you could put this logout call in a function, and then call the enclosing function in the catch field, although if an error keeps occurring it will be stuck in an endless loop, so I would advise against.

If an error is occurring, clearly something is not right and they are not being signed out for a reason so it may be worth handling specific logout errors instead of trying to "force logout".